# product of list iteratively

Tags: list, haskell, product

I'm trying to learn coding in Haskell.

I started with an easy example "the product of a list".

```
product :: [Integer] -> Integer  
product []     = 1  
product (x:xs) = x * product xs
```

I finished this quickly.
Another way is the product function in the API. (product List -> product)

I wonder if there is another iterative way to solve my problem?

Comment: Depends. What exactly do you mean by iterative?

Comment: I mean a non-recursive way. Don't know if it's possible.

Comment: Not using recursion *yourself* or not using recursion *at all*? I don't think the latter is possible in Haskell, but there are many functions which do (a specific pattern of) recursion for you.

Comment: depending on how you intend to use `product`, I might set the null list to return zero.

Comment: @groovy That's not the usual definition of product in mathematics and all applications of it, mostly because the product of the empty set being one is far more useful in almost all cases. If there was a use case for this behavior, I wouldn't call it `product` to avoid confusion. Also, I'm curious: do you have a use case in mind?

Comment: @delnan Thanks for the informative comment; I have many holes in my education... I guess my thought was, for example, to avoid having to test each list twice in a `sum . map . product`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a fold:

```
product :: Num a => [a] -> a
product xs = foldl (*) 1 xs
```

This can also be done strictly with `foldl'` or `foldr`, the differences mostly are performance, but since you're just starting out I'll skip that lecture this time.

---

So what does a fold do?  Let's start with the basic definition of `foldl`:

```
foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldl f acc [] = acc
foldl f acc (x:xs) = foldl f (f acc x) xs
```

What this does is takes a function `f :: a -> b -> a` which takes an *accumulator* and an additional value, which is fed to it from the list of values.  It iteratively applies this function, generating a new accumulator at each step, until it runs out of values in the list.  For `(*)` it looks something like

```
> foldl (*) 1 [1, 2, 3, 4]
|   foldl (*) (1 * 1) [2, 3, 4] = foldl (*) 1 [2, 3, 4]
|   foldl (*) (1 * 2) [3, 4]    = foldl (*) 2 [3, 4]
|   foldl (*) (2 * 3) [4]       = foldl (*) 6 [4]
|   foldl (*) (6 * 4) []        = foldl (*) 24 []
|   24
```

I should add that this isn't exactly how it's performed in memory unless you use `foldl'`, which is the strict version, but it's easier to follow this way.

Comment: Why include the empty list case, doesn't `foldl` handle that itself?

Comment: @delnan Habit, `foldl` does take care of it, fixed it now

Answer (score 1):

Well in Haskell we don't have loops so iterative is relative, but here's the "functional iteration approach"

```
 product = foldl' (*) 1
```

folds are the equivalent of loops in imperative languages. `foldl'` in particular is tail recursive and strict so it will run in constant space, similar to a loop.

If we were to write it explicitly

```
 product = go 1
   where go accum (x:xs) = go (accum * x) xs
         go accum _      = accum -- Subtle performances
                                 -- differences with strictness
```

This is still recursive, but will compile to similar assembly.